# kendo grid Save and Cancel operation from Api call Angular 7

Tags: kendo-ui, angular7, webapi

i have bounded a api call response to kendo grid and am able to bind the data in the columns and to do edit and save for a inline edit which i have bound in my html , I see lots of samples binding through component template am not sure if that works in my approach can someone give me some links as am new to kendo. I need to get all the editing row data and then wen i save button it goes to my put api call.TIA

my application

HTML

```
       <kendo-grid [data]="ForecastProductionQuantity" 
              [pageSize]="10" [pageable]="true" [resizable]="true"
              [scrollable]="scrollable" [filterable]="true"
              [height]="650">
           <kendo-grid-column field="AmgName">
           <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              {{gridHeaders["AmgName"]}}
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProdQty.ProdQty0">
      <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
        {{gridHeaders["ForecastType0"]}}
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProdQty.ProdQty1">
      <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
        {{gridHeaders["ForecastType1"]}}
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>

  </kendo-grid>
Component.ts
 loadForecastQuantityData() {
//keeping it 0 will be incorporated after Go click is integrated will be changed as per save input 
this.allocationSetupID = 0;
return this.restapi.getForecastProductionQuantityData(this.allocationSetupID, this.ForecastID).subscribe((data: {}) => {
  this.ForecastProductionQuantity = data;

  for (var prod in this.ForecastProductionQuantity) {

    this.gridHeaders = {
      AmgName: "Amg Name",
      ForecastType0: this.ForecastProductionQuantity[prod].Forecast_type.ForecastType0 + " " + this.ForecastProductionQuantity[prod].ProdMonth.ProdMonth0,
      ForecastType1: this.ForecastProductionQuantity[prod].Forecast_type.ForecastType1 + " " + this.ForecastProductionQuantity[prod].ProdMonth.ProdMonth1,

    }

  }

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);

})
 }
  service.ts
getForecastProductionQuantityData(allocationSetupID: any, ForecastID: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(this.apiURL + '/GetProductionVolume/' + allocationSetupID + '/' + 
  ForecastID )
  .pipe(
    retry(1),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed Kendo's example [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-template-forms/)?  It is what I use in my application.  In the `(save)="saveHandler($event)"` function in TypeScript, send the data to your API service to save.  The asynchronous view will automatically update after the data posts.

Comment: Yes have seen this example , could you mind sharing a sample api call of how you read the data as am not able to bind the fetch method with callback.TIA

Comment: @user12093961 we use OData v4 in .NET hosted with IIS as our REST backend; Telerik's Northwind example back end uses OData as well.

Comment: Thanks, Am able to bind the data i changed Jsonp request to Json get and able to bind, however in save did u mean to use the saveHandler($event) in the button click event instead of saveChanges(grid)?!

Comment: @user12093961 you need to use the [`SaveCommandDirective`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/SaveCommandDirective/) for in-line editing.  It triggers the `save` event which in turn calls the function `saveHandler`.